# TeXworks + pdflatex + PSTricks autopp suffix problem

Tags: pdftex, compiling, pstricks, texworks

I have managed to make PSTricks work with TeXworks. However after compilation it adds `-autopp` to the basename of the pdf file, e.g. `report.pdf` becomes `report-autopp.pdf`. As a result TeXworks is not able to preview the file in a window.

How can I make TeXworks preview the pdf file? Am I doing something wrong? Here is my tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{pspicture}(4,5)
\psframe(0.7,2)(3.3,3)
\rput(2,2.5){First Example}
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you run the document with `pdflatex -shell-escape`? See http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#texworks

Comment: @Herbert yup. I've setup TeXworks for that.

Comment: and have you Perl installed? If not then use `\usepackage{pstricks}\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` and tell us what your log file reports.

Comment: I have installed Perl and tried again, did not work. Using `\usepackage{pstricks}\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` worked. Does this mean my TeX distribution is too old?

Comment: run your original example and post the logfile where error messages appear.

Comment: here you go http://pastebin.com/EwzquDak

Comment: you didn't run the example with the `-shell-escape` option.

Comment: No, I did. If I run without `-shell-escape`, I get `"shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled: auto-pst-pdf will not work!` error.

Comment: ok, I see. Maybe a problem with PSTricks. Can you try `\usepackage{pstricks}\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`?

Comment: @Herbert that seems to work, thank you. I will accept it as the answer if you write.

Comment: answer added below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
```

I'll have a look at the `pstricks.sty` why it didn't work under Windows. With Linux it is no problem. However, you have to run it with

```
pdflatex --shell-escape <file>
```

for TeXnicCenter and others see http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#TXC

Comment: Guys, I'm facing the same issue. pstricks doesn't work with pdflatex on windows as it is expected.

Comment: @nimcap, I have the same "autopp suffix problem". My TeX distribution is ProTeXt-3.1.3-060313

Comment: I suppose you forgot  the `-shell-escape`. See my edited answer.

Comment: nope, I have tried all possible ways :( how can i post my question? as an answer?

Comment: @maksmara [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) are more than welcome! Please use the "[Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do with the following approach. Compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex` where `main.tex` is as follows.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{figure.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,5)
\psframe(0.7,2)(3.3,3)
\rput{90}(2,2.5){First Example}
\pscircle[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt](2,2.5){2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\foreach \compiler/\extension in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None}/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space figure.\extension}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{figure}
\caption{This is my figure.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

- `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` is important here to avoid `ps2pdf` to automatically rotate the figure. Try it by yourself, remove `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`.